# Calculate the future velocity in FixedUpdate when given a force and work out if it's negative to the current velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using relative force on an object. The idea is

- If I apply the up arrow it will add force to the direction it's moving.
- When I apply the down arrow, it will apply negative force to the direction of motion slowing the object down.

The issue I am trying to solve is, when the down arrow is pressed enough that the object eventually slows down, I need the object to stop and not change directions.

In short what I need to do, is on a `FixedUpdate` pass work out if the objects velocity (or Direction) is going to be negative to the direction (or velocity) of movement. This seems possible, however I am not sure of the right calculation `AddForce` Uses.

My guess is I'll need to use some calculation and the [Vector3.Dot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html) method

> Dot Product of two vectors.
>
> The dot product is a float value equal to the magnitudes of the two
>   vectors multiplied together and then multiplied by the cosine of the
>   angle between them.

Something like this

```
var future = (forward) * _body.velocity.magnitude * _body.mass;
```

However, I am not sure what's needed.

**Given**

```
private Rigidbody _body;

public float Speed;
```

**Physics calculation**

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{

  // get the controls
  var hAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
  var vAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

  if (_body.velocity == Vector3.zero)
  {
     // this is just to give some forward moment when stationary
     // this will change at some stage and not my problem
     var movement = new Vector3(hAxis, 0.0f, vAxis);
     if (vAxis > 0)
        _body.AddForce(movement * Speed);
  }
  else
  {

     // get the direction we are traveling
     var direction = _body.velocity.normalized;

     // calculate the vertical force from the controls
     var forward = direction * vAxis * Speed;

     // Calculate the side force from teh controls
     var side = Vector3.Cross(direction, Vector3.up) * hAxis * -1f * Speed;

     // This is equation is wrong. 
     var future = (forward) * _body.velocity.magnitude * _body.mass;

     // what I am trying to say, is if the future velocity is negative
     // i.e the user has pressed the back arrow so much it will go backwards
     // then I want to come to a dead stop, and not apply any backwards force
     if (Vector3.Dot(direction, future.normalized) < 0)
     {
        _body.velocity = Vector3.zero;         
        return;
     }

     _body.AddForce(forward + side);
  }
}
```

Comment: `Final Velocity = Starting Velocity + Step Acceleration`, with `Step Acceleration = Time * Force/Mass`.

Comment: You're probably just better off testing for `is it negative NOW` rather than trying to predict.

Comment: @Immersive negative now, wont allow it to naturally slow down with force applied, ie it will be just dead stop, however i am playing with your calculations they seems promising

Comment: It would only "dead stop" if you are applying too much negative force add once .. behaving natural because this is what happens if you brake to hard. I'ld say Immersive is right and clamping the current velocity to `0 <= X <= forward` should be enough.

Comment: @derHugo or someone if you feel like writing up an answer id be happy to try it and mark it accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no real Physics pro but I'll try my best ;)

You could do the clamping int the next call of `FixedUpdate` so after the `_body.velocity` is updated

```
public Rigidbody _body;
public float Speed;

// store the last forward direction
private Vector3 lastForward;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Check and clamp the current velocity against the last one
    // so after forces from last call have been applied
    if (Vector3.Dot(lastForward, _body.velocity.normalized) < 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Clamped negative");
        _body.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    }

    lastForward = _body.velocity.normalized;

    var hAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    var vAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    // == for Vector3 has only a precision of 0.00001
    // to be sure you coul use this instead
    if (Mathf.Approximately(_body.velocity.magnitude, 0))
    {
        if (vAxis > 0) _body.AddForce(new Vector3(hAxis, 0.0f, vAxis) * Speed);
    }
    else
    {
        var forwardForce = Speed * vAxis * lastForward;
        var sideForce = Speed * hAxis * -1f * Vector3.Cross(lastForward, Vector3.up);

        _body.AddForce(forwardForce + sideForce);
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively I guess what Immersive ment you could instead of using `AddForce` calculate the force yourself directly in `velocity` like

```
public Rigidbody _body;
public float Speed;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    var currentVelocity = _body.velocity;
    var currentDirection = currentVelocity.normalized;

    var hAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    var vAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    if(Mathf.Approximately(_body.velocity.magnitude, 0))
    {
        // Directly calculating the velocity as Immersive said:
        // newVelocity = currentVelocity + Time.deltaTime * Force / Mass
        // where Force = direction * Speed
        // 
        // Ofcourse you could also just use AddForce for this case but
        // just for consistency I would use the same method for both cases
        if(vAxis>0) _body.velocity += new Vector3(hAxis, 0.0f, vAxis) * (Time.deltaTime * Speed / _body.mass);
    }
    else
    {
        var forwardForce = Speed * vAxis * currentDirection;
        var sideForce = Speed * hAxis * -1f * Vector3.Cross(currentDirection, Vector3.up);

        // calculate the future velocity directly without using AddForce
        // (see comment above)
        var newVelocity = currentVelocity + (forwardForce + sideForce) * (Time.deltaTime / _body.mass);

        // Only use this velocity if the new direction is still forward
        // otherwise stop
        _body.velocity = Vector3.Dot(currentVelocity, newVelocity) < 0 ? Vector3.zero : newVelocity;
    }
}
```

---

Arrived at the PC and tested it now ;) both should basically work

Using `AddForce` and clamping in the next call

[image]

Using Calculated `velocity`

[image]

Comment: Oh... warranty implied!. anyway thanks, ill give it a try soon

Comment: @TheGeneral just arrived and checked ;) see the updates